# Naked.toolshed not sending all the parameters info

Tags: javascript, python, arguments, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

Here is a little example of my code in python:

```
from Naked.toolshed.shell import execute_js, muterun_js

caption=str("fsf sfsggs")

link="sggdhbwdhsrh"

print(caption)

arg_in = f"{link} {caption}"

response = execute_js('C:/Users/Me/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/t.js', arg_in)
```

And then the js code that prints those parameters only to see if the script recibed the info as it should:

```
var link = process.argv[2]

var caption= process.argv[3]

console.log(caption)
```

But then I only get the first word in the cmd:

```
fsf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command line arguments are delimited by spaces, so the `caption` value is getting split into 2 args.

You're only logging `process.argv[3]`, which is actually the 4th argument of 5. You can see them all with `console.log(process.argv)`...

```
[
  'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe',
  'E:\\proj\\so\\t.js',
  'sggdhbwdhsrh',
  'fsf',
  'sfsggs'
]
```

The array element indices are zero-based (of course!). So `sfsggs` is in `process.argv[4]`

If you want to pass the `caption` as one argument containing a space, then in the Python you can enclose in speech marks `"` like so...

```
caption='"fsf sfsggs"'
```

Comment: No problemo :-)

Comment: Feel free to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) this answer when you're ready ;)